# Pandas: get the first occurrence grouping by keys

Tags: python, pandas

If I have following dataframe

```
| id | timestamp           | code | id2
| 10 | 2017-07-12 13:37:00 | 206  | a1
| 10 | 2017-07-12 13:40:00 | 206  | a1
| 10 | 2017-07-12 13:55:00 | 206  | a1
| 10 | 2017-07-12 19:00:00 | 206  | a2
| 11 | 2017-07-12 13:37:00 | 206  | a1
...
```

I need to group by `id, id2` columns and get the first occurrence of `timestamp` value, e.g. for `id=10, id2=a1, timestamp=2017-07-12 13:37:00`.

I googled it and found some possible solutions, but cant figure out how to realize them properly. This probably should be something like:

```
df.groupby(["id", "id2"])["timestamp"].apply(lambda x: ....)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df.groupby(["id", "id2"])["timestamp"].first()
```

Or [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','id2'])
```

For same output:

```
df1 = df.groupby(["id", "id2"], as_index=False)["timestamp"].first()
print (df1)
   id id2            timestamp
0  10  a1  2017-07-12 13:37:00
1  10  a2  2017-07-12 19:00:00
2  11  a1  2017-07-12 13:37:00

df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','id2'])[['id','id2','timestamp']]
print (df1)
   id id2            timestamp
0  10  a1  2017-07-12 13:37:00
1  10  a2  2017-07-12 19:00:00
2  11  a1  2017-07-12 13:37:00
```

Answer (score 0):

One can create a new column after merging id and id2 strings, then remove rows where it is duplicated:

```
df['newcol'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x.id) + str(x.id2), axis=1)
df = df[~df.newcol.duplicated()].iloc[:,:4]   # iloc used to remove new column.
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id              timestamp  code  id2
0  10   2017-07-12 13:37:00    206   a1
3  10   2017-07-12 19:00:00    206   a2
4  11   2017-07-12 13:37:00    206   a1
```